# Series of new, mysterious ActiveRecord errors introduced into production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have rails 3.2.13 app that I've had active and online for 5 years now. A couple weeks ago, I made some minimal changes (html/css changes in views), and ever since then, all my deploys to AWS have been seemingly corrupted. I'm getting a series of ActiveRecord or rendering errors which appeared to have come out of nowhere. What's baffling to me, is that I changed nothing related ActiveRecord or any of the core components of Rails, but these services are failing on something like 1% of the requests.

And it's not just 1 error, it's a number of errors that appear unrelated, except for the fact that they never occurred on my system up until June 03. When I follow the backtrace of the error, it never leads me to an issue in my code, just to a core Rails file. When I re-try a URL that may have resulted in an error a few moments ago, it works fine for me. It's like the underlying issue is only evident for a moment and then it's back to normal. And I can't figure out what is causing these errors in the first place. Here are a few of the errors I'm seeing regularly now:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass`

from file `/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:401`

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'has_key?' for nil:NilClass`

from file `/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:72`

`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: item_color`

I see this one above with any attribute -- and obviously the attribute is actually in the record, as 99%+ of requests to that URL are completed successfully, it's only happening on some requests.

`NameError: '' is not allowed as an instance variable name`

from file `/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:126`

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<MyProduct>`

from file `/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407`

There are about 20 more errors like these above that are similar in character. Any idea what I might do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: maybe in the new deploy with those changes, some gems were updated, is that a possibility with your deploy process?

Comment: Do you keep your Gemfile.lock in version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by the `maxminddb` gem. I replaced it by using the `hive_geoip2` gem, which relies on libmaxminddb, instead.

I'm still not sure why `maxminddb` was causing these problems, but its been 24 hours since making the change, and the issues appear to be gone.